# How by session can I post "username" and "gender" in the url?

Tags: php

I have only coded for a month, and less than 3 days with php. Thank-you for your any assistance I can get on this.

```
<?PHP
require_once("session.php");
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->RegisterUser())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("thank-you.html");
   }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <title>Contact us</title>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/pwdwidget.css" />
    <script src="scripts/pwdwidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form Code Start -->

<div id='fg_membersite'>

 <!-- I believe the problem is right in here. -->
<form action="session.php" method="post">        
<form id='register' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
  </form>  
<fieldset >
<legend>Register</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action ="radioButton.php">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'male' required value="1"
<?PHP print $male_status; ?>
>male

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'female' required value="2"
<?PHP print $female_status; ?>
>female

<P>
</FORM>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >UserName*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container' style='height:80px;'>
    <label for='password' >Password*:</label><br/>
    <div class='pwdwidgetdiv' id='thepwddiv' ></div>
    <noscript>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
    </noscript>    
    <div id='register_password_errorloc' class='error' style='clear:both'></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[
    var pwdwidget = new PasswordWidget('thepwddiv','password');
    pwdwidget.MakePWDWidget();

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("register");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please provide a valid email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please provide a username");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","Please provide a password");

// ]]>
</script>

<!--
Form Code End (see html-form-guide.com for more info.)
-->

</body>
</html>
```

> This file does work well, but for the fact that the current setup does not show the "username" and "gender" in the url after submission.

```
<?php
session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['gender'])) {
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $gen = $_POST['gender'];

  echo 'Username: '. $username. ' - gender: '. $gender;
}
?>
```

> This is the session.php file I have been trying to use.

Comment: You access session data via $_SESSION not $_GET.  Is that what you are looking for?  If you want data submitted from a form using method=post, then you need $_POST.  You should read the php manual about SUPERGLOBALS.

Comment: What do you mean `post` Post is a type of web request with parameters, usually done by forms, but sometimes using libraries like CURL.

Comment: Ok, I fixed you Question, the misplaced `<!-- Form Code Start -->` comment was messing it all up.  Where the form was not even showing.  Anyway, I fixed it, yea.

Comment: Thank-you ArtisticPhoenix.  This is my first post here, and I am still trying to show where I believe the problem is in register.php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my session variable in a different page with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403784/how-can-i-access-my-session-variable-in-a-different-page-with-php)

Comment: First thing please have a look at get and post request type They both have different behaviour. So go ahead and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get.
Secondly you should have a look at your html.
Next thing is have a close look here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp  It is really a good starting point for forms and handling forms in php.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you are trying to do with session variables here, but just to keep your data in session, do this

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $user
$_SESSION["gender"] = $gender;
```

So that you can use `$_SESSION["user"]` and `$_SESSION["gender"]` throughout your project until session exists.

Don't forget to start the session.

#### UPDATE

As you recently changed form method to `post`, change variables in `session.php` to `$_POST["user"]` and so on.

#### NEXT

```
<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action ="radioButton.php">

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'male' required value="1"
<?PHP print $male_status; ?>
>male

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'female' required value="2"
<?PHP print $female_status; ?>
>female

<P>
</FORM>
```

You don't need form here. remove form starting and closing tags.

**Now as I see 'username' field name in `register.php`, change `name` to `username` inside `session.php`**

Comment: @chrisx2600 Yes, I think so. He has messed up form elements there.

Comment: I have edited my submission.  In the sessions.php file, I believe the "get" should be "post".  Also in the register.php file the way I have it I get an "Could not get Form Object "register".

Comment: `session.php?user=john&gender=male`

This way, you will be passing values to session.php via GET method.

Comment: How do I do that so that for any user?  Thank-you by the way for your quick response.

Comment: Welcome, @chrisx2600. Please see the update for my answer.

Comment: I have changed "GET" to "POST" in session.php

Comment: `<form id='register' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
  </form> ` 

What are you doing with this form? If you are not sure why you making this, please remove.

Comment: @ Suresh Pokharel -It could not get Form object Register, and when I submitted the form, it does not show username nor gender. For some reason I cannot edit the session.php code on here, only the register.

Comment: I mean you should have two fields with name 'user' and 'gender' in your register.php

Comment: I managed to put the username and gender into Session.  Yet, now I am stuck trying to get a new page to contain the username and gender in the url.  I am not sure the format to do this. I did this by "Post" method.

Answer (score 0):

> Very simple Session using this way:----

```
session sets:--

session_start();

$_SESSION['value'] = 'tested';
```

session gets :--

```
echo $_SESSION['value'];
```

**output:--tested**

Comment: You should reformat this answer because it is likely to confuse new developers.

Comment: why can you tell me?

Comment: This is very simple solution easy undetstand all peoples/developers.

Comment: 1. Quote blocks are not meant to be used where you used them.  2. Your grey php code block will cause errors.