# Implementing Timer, handling on Refresh?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written a component that will keep track of time. I am currently using `Localstorage` to save the `currentTime` just in case a user hits Refresh. However, I found that this solution is not a really good one becasue the user can edit `localstorage`. On the other hand, I can use the database to store this information, but it will slow down my page which I do not want.

Is there any alternative solution beside using `LocalStorage` to store my time? I do not want user to edit the `localstorage`.

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    private start: number = null;
    private uiTimerId: number = null;

    constructor() {
    }

    private updateUI(): void {

        let delta = performance.now() - this.start;
        this.someUIElement.textContent = delta.toFixed() + "ms";
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.start = parseFloat( window.localStorage.getItem( "timerStart" ) );
        if( !this.start ) {
            this.start = performance.now();
            window.localStorage.setItem( "timerStart", this.start );
        }

        this.uiTimerId = window.setInterval( this.updateUI.bind(this), 100 ); // 100ms UI updates, not 1000ms to reduce UI jitter
    }

    buttonClick = function() {
        if( this.uiTimerId != null ) {
            window.clearInterval( this.uiTimerId );
            window.localStorage.removeItem( "timerStart" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking if theres other solution beside using Database to store it. For efficiency purpose.

Comment: From the database possibility, I assume you have to login to use this service. Does the currentTime need to be retained between different logins or can it be discarded once you log out?

Comment: @Emenpy Either keep it in a service, or learn how to use a redux like store https://github.com/ngrx/store ... I dont see why a simple service wont do :p

Comment: @FRECIA Even if it's in service, a refresh will start the timer over.

Comment: @NocNit I am using a timer to measure how long a user stay in a certain page. Once log out/log back in, the timer is reset. However, i do not want it to reset when a user refresh a page. By storing in localStorage, i can retrieve the time from localstorage if it was reset.

Comment: @Emenpy Just a follow up, did our comments/answer help you solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative might be to save the time the user accessed the page in the **session** on the server side. A session is stored in server memory and tied to a login, and can hold information on the server which makes it secure. Once the user logs out, the information is discarded, so it's more efficient than a database.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages) has a PHP example of how to store something in the session. The neat thing there is that they show how a session is remembered between pages, so you will always have access to currentTime.

[Another good SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403784/how-can-i-access-my-session-variable-in-a-different-page-with-php)